# OR Condition Return Error in GQL ( Google app engine) Why?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

When i use the OR condion in GQL it return error messege tht "**BadQueryError: Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol OR** . Why?

```
db.GqlQuery("Select * from vendor where access='public' OR organisation_id='"+ orgid +"'")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    GQL does not have an OR operator. However, it does have an IN operator, 
which provides a limited form of OR.
```

Docs clearly says that GQL doesn't have an OR operator..

You could do something like this ..Make two queries and combine the results...

```
  vendors=vendor.all()
  pub_vendors = vendors.filter("access = ","public")
  vendors=vendor.all()
  org_vendors = vendors.filter("organisation_id = ",orgid)
  results = pub_vendors.extend(org_vendors)
```

Comment: Your example would be an AND, and almost certainly isn't what OP wants.

Comment: If the vendors have a datetime property, how would I sort 'results' by time using GQL (usually done with `ORDER BY time ASC/DESC`)?  Unless there's a nifty trick, it seems unnecessarily complex to have to do it programmatically

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'extend'`. You need to call `fetch` before you can `extend`.